# Apple MDM - Push notification topic

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I'm setting up a MDM server and I've passed all the certificates generation steps. I can enrol successfully on my mdm server. But when I send the wakeup push notification I get no response back from the device.

I'm using the [Java APNS](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) library to send the mdm push notification. Here's the code:

```
final String token = getToken("dlfkjgldfjglfl"); 
ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
                .withDelegate(listener)
                .withCert(P12_FILE_PATH, "password")
                .withProductionDestination()
                .build(); 
final String payloadString = APNS.newPayload().mdm("push_magic_token").build(); 

// Send the wake up push notification to APNS
service.push(token, payloadString);
```

I get no errors or exceptions with the code above and the `delegate` prints `environment:production|push notification sent|notification:Message(Id=1; Token=the_token; Payload={"mdm":"magictoken"})` Which means the push was sent to APNS with success but the device never wakes up and communicates with my mdm server.

After further reading on the Apple documentation it states that there is the need to specify a topic for the push notification but the library has no method to set the topic.

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1):

> **apns-topic:** The topic of the remote notification, which is typically the bundle ID for your app. The certificate you create in
>   Member Center must include the capability for this topic. If your
>   certificate includes multiple topics, you must specify a value for
>   this header. If you omit this header and your APNs certificate does
>   not specify multiple topics, the APNs server uses the certificate’s
>   Subject as the default topic.

From this I presume the Java APNS library is using the topic as the certificate subject.

To generate the certificates I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/thrasr/mdm-server) but the `vendor.p12` file generated wasn't being accepted by APNS as my push notification certificate (handshake error). After some googling I figured out some people also had this problem and they fixed it generating another `.p12` from the `mdm.cer` downloaded from Apple generated MDM Certificate using:

```
openssl x509 -in mdm.cer -inform DER -out push_developer.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in vendor.p12 -out vendor.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey vendor.pem -in push_developer.pem -out push_developer.p12
```

The certificate I am using as my push notifications is then `push_developer.p12`

I'm not skilled with certificates management so I am lost. 
My question is how can I set the topic in the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out how the topic works. It is indeed within the certificate.

As I'm on a mac I'll explain how to get the proper certificate on a mac.

1. Download the MDM certificate generated by Apple (you should be able to download it from your MDM control panel on the Apple website)
2. Install the certificate in your machine
3. Open Keychain and find the certificate you just installed on step 2. It should be something like: APSP:slkjl34435-sdkj-sfd0-34o5uoijsdf
4. Click on the arrow and you should see the private key.
5. Select the certificate. Right click and select "Export 1 item". **Only export your certificate and NOT the certificate + private key.**
6. Save the .p12 file and use it as your MDM push notification certificate.

With these steps I managed to get the topic to work but my device is still not waking up. I'll open a new question regarding the device not waking up as this was more related to the topic and the certificate (I thought the device didn't wake up because the topic was incorrect).